# org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, spring, utf-8

I am getting below exception when I am calling rest service.

> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content
>   type 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported
>                 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:152)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>                 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:181)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
>                 at

**Code**

```
    //    This method calls the rest service


        @Override
        public TransactionSearchResults callSearchTransactions(TransactionSearchCriteria criteria, int page, int size) {

        HttpEntity<TransactionSearchCriteria> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<TransactionSearchCriteria>(criteria, getCommonHeaders(new HttpHeaders()));

        Map<String, Integer> params = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        params.put("size", size);
        params.put("page", page);

        return restTemplate.exchange(urlBase + "/transaction?size={size}&page={page}", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, TransactionSearchResults.class, params).getBody();

        }

    // Api which caters to rest call

        @Controller
        @RequestMapping("/transaction")
        public class TransactionStatusController extends BaseController { ... }

    //Controller method for rest call 
        @ResponseBody
        @RequestMapping(produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, method = RequestMethod.POST , consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            public com.rest.TransactionSearchResults searchTransactions(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page,
// Using request Param to retireve criteria                         
@RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size, @Valid     @RequestBody com.rest.TransactionSearchCriteria criteria) {
// This gets relevant results and return it to rest call
    return convert(transactionService.search(convert(criteria), page, size));

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. The pom entry given below which was conflicting with jackson core libraries. Just removed it and it all worked fine.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
<version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your controller is implemented such as to accept only JSON values i.e. `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`; thus the error which clearly states that XML is not supported.

In case XML is intended type update the controller to include `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML` or `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_Value`

Comment: I tried removing the consumes attribute from the controller but still it shows up same error. Also none of the post rest calls are working in the project. Looks like some issue with httpMessageconverters.

Comment: please post your relevant configs (viz. spring, maven etc)