# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

> Spring boot version 2.4.4
>
> Java version 15

```
@Bean
    public WebClient webClient() {
        return WebClient.builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .defaultHeaders(header -> header.setBasicAuth("test",
                        "testpwd"))
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.newConnection()))
                .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder().codecs(configurer -> {
                    configurer.defaultCodecs().jaxb2Encoder(new Jaxb2XmlEncoder());
                    configurer.defaultCodecs().jaxb2Decoder(new Jaxb2XmlDecoder());
                }).build()).build();
        
    }
```

Using Spring boot 2.4.4 webclient and trying to consume the service with XML reponse.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> retrieveServices() {

        // Headers can be passed here or while building the client
        Mono<DirectoryOfService> serviceMono = webClient
             .get().uri("/api/v1/test/services")
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .retrieve().bodyToMono(DirectoryOfService.class);

    }
```

**Error:-**

```
    org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Could not create JAXBContext for class [class com.test.model.DirectoryOfService]: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.xml.JaxbContextContainer.lambda$getJaxbContext$0(JaxbContextContainer.java:58) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Body from GET https://test.com/api/v1/services [DefaultClientResponse]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/api/v1/services" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.http.codec.xml.JaxbContextContainer.lambda$getJaxbContext$0(JaxbContextContainer.java:58) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.xml.JaxbContextContainer.getJaxbContext(JaxbContextContainer.java:52) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.xml.JaxbContextContainer.createUnmarshaller(JaxbContextContainer.java:47) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.xml.Jaxb2XmlDecoder.initUnmarshaller(Jaxb2XmlDecoder.java:235) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.xml.Jaxb2XmlDecoder.unmarshal(Jaxb2XmlDecoder.java:216) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.xml.Jaxb2XmlDecoder.decode(Jaxb2XmlDecoder.java:195) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.xml.Jaxb2XmlDecoder.lambda$decodeToMono$2(Jaxb2XmlDecoder.java:183) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:159) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:259) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:401) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:416) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:470) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:685) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:94) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-codec-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1534) ~[netty-handler-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1283) ~[netty-handler-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1330) ~[netty-handler-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:508) ~[netty-codec-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:447) ~[netty-codec-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[netty-codec-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:278) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:421) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.xml.JaxbContextContainer.lambda$getJaxbContext$0(JaxbContextContainer.java:54) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.xml.JaxbContextContainer.getJaxbContext(JaxbContextContainer.java:52) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.xml.JaxbContextContainer.createUnmarshaller(JaxbContextContainer.java:47) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.xml.Jaxb2XmlDecoder.initUnmarshaller(Jaxb2XmlDecoder.java:235) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.xml.Jaxb2XmlDecoder.unmarshal(Jaxb2XmlDecoder.java:216) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.xml.Jaxb2XmlDecoder.decode(Jaxb2XmlDecoder.java:195) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.xml.Jaxb2XmlDecoder.lambda$decodeToMono$2(Jaxb2XmlDecoder.java:183) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:159) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:259) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:401) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:416) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:470) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:685) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:94) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-codec-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
```

build.gradle,

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-core', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'
        
}
```

After removing com.sun.xml.bind and adding glassfish, getting the error below.

> implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.1'

**Error :**

```
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Could not create JAXBContext for class [class com.test.model.DirectoryOfService]: 10 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions; nested exception is com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 10 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "section"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.getSection()
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
Class has two properties of the same name "name"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.test.model.Section.getName()
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String com.test.model.Section.name
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
Class has two properties of the same name "test"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.util.List com.test.model.Section.getTest()
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.util.List com.test.model.Section.test
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
Class has two properties of the same name "code"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.test.model.Test.getCode()
        at com.test.model.Test
        at private java.util.List com.test.model.Section.test
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String com.test.model.Test.code
        at com.test.model.Test
        at private java.util.List com.test.model.Section.test
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
Class has two properties of the same name "currency"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.test.model.Test.getCurrency()
        at com.test.model.Test
        at private java.util.List com.test.model.Section.test
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String com.test.model.Test.currency
        at com.test.model.Test
        at private java.util.List com.test.model.Section.test
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
Class has two properties of the same name "includes"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.test.model.Test.getIncludes()
        at com.test.model.Test
        at private java.util.List com.test.model.Section.test
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String com.test.model.Test.includes
        at com.test.model.Test
        at private java.util.List com.test.model.Section.test
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
Class has two properties of the same name "name"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.test.model.Test.getName()
        at com.test.model.Test
        at private java.util.List com.test.model.Section.test
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String com.test.model.Test.name
        at com.test.model.Test
        at private java.util.List com.test.model.Section.test
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
Class has two properties of the same name "nonDiscountable"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public boolean com.test.model.Test.isNonDiscountable()
        at com.test.model.Test
        at private java.util.List com.test.model.Section.test
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private boolean com.test.model.Test.nonDiscountable
        at com.test.model.Test
        at private java.util.List com.test.model.Section.test
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
Class has two properties of the same name "replicate"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public int com.test.model.Test.getReplicate()
        at com.test.model.Test
        at private java.util.List com.test.model.Section.test
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private int com.test.model.Test.replicate
        at com.test.model.Test
        at private java.util.List com.test.model.Section.test
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
Class has two properties of the same name "validFrom"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.util.Date com.test.model.Test.getValidFrom()
        at com.test.model.Test
        at private java.util.List com.test.model.Section.test
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.util.Date com.test.model.Test.validFrom
        at com.test.model.Test
        at private java.util.List com.test.model.Section.test
        at com.test.model.Section
        at private com.test.model.Section com.test.model.DirectoryOfService.section
        at com.test.model.DirectoryOfService
```

Sample response file,

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<DirectoryOfService>
    <Section Name="Directory">
        <Test>
            <Name>Mike</Name>
            <Code>USA</Code>
            <Replicate>0</Replicate>
            <ValidFrom>2016-06-30</ValidFrom>
            <Includes>Test Includes</Includes>
            <Currency>None</Currency>
            <NonDiscountable>false</NonDiscountable>
        </Test>
        <Test>
            <Name>Bingo</Name>
            <Code>USA</Code>
            <Replicate>0</Replicate>
            <ValidFrom>2016-06-30</ValidFrom>
            <Includes>Test Includes</Includes>
            <Currency>None</Currency>
            <NonDiscountable>false</NonDiscountable>
        </Test>
    </Section>
</DirectoryOfService>
```

**Model classes,**

**DirectoryOfService class,**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement(name="DirectoryOfService")
public class DirectoryOfService {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "Section")
    private Section section;

    
    public Section getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setSection(Section section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

}
```

**Section calss,**

```
    @XmlRootElement(name="Section")
    public class Section {
    
        @XmlElementRef(name = "Test")
        private List<Test> test;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "Name")
        private String name;
        //public String text;
    
        public List<Test> getTest() {
            return test;
        }
    
        
        public void setTest(List<Test> test) {
            this.test = test;
        }
    
        
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    
    }

Test class,

@XmlRootElement(name = "Test")
public class Test {

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "Code")
    private String code;
    @XmlElement(name = "Replicate")
    private int replicate;
    @XmlElement(name = "ValidFrom")
    private Date validFrom;
    @XmlElement(name = "Includes")
    private String includes;
    @XmlElement(name = "Currency")
    private String currency;
    @XmlElement(name = "NonDiscountable")
    private boolean nonDiscountable;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    
    public int getReplicate() {
        return replicate;
    }

    
    public void setReplicate(int replicate) {
        this.replicate = replicate;
    }

    
    public Date getValidFrom() {
        return validFrom;
    }

    
    public void setValidFrom(Date validFrom) {
        this.validFrom = validFrom;
    }

    
    public String getIncludes() {
        return includes;
    }

    
    public void setIncludes(String includes) {
        this.includes = includes;
    }

    
    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    
    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    
    public boolean isNonDiscountable() {
        return nonDiscountable;
    }

    
    public void setNonDiscountable(boolean nonDiscountable) {
        this.nonDiscountable = nonDiscountable;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try the accepted answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185713/org-springframework-web-httpmediatypenotsupportedexception-content-type-applic?rq=1 ?

Comment: I tried the accepted answer and still not working with Spring webclient.

Comment: have you try replacing the ExchangeStrategies instead of configuring the default ones
`WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://test.com")
            .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder().codecs((configurer) -> {
            configurer.defaultCodecs().jaxb2Encoder(new Jaxb2XmlEncoder());
            configurer.defaultCodecs().jaxb2Decoder(new Jaxb2XmlDecoder());
        }).build();`

Comment: I tried this and it doesnt help.

Comment: What is the spring boot version that you are using? I am not able to reproduce this error at all in a sample project I just created.

Comment: Spring boot version 2.4.3

Comment: @user1578872 Although you tested similar approaches, please, consider review [this Github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20256), especially the [last comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20256#issuecomment-558595570), I think it can be helpful.

Comment: @jccampanero, Made some progress with the above link and getting a diff error now.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory

Comment: Have you tried a different JAXB implementation? I _think_ the com.sun ones are pretty old/unmaintained. https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.jaxb-impl

Comment: @wolfcastle Do you mean // 
"implementation group: 'jakarta.xml.bind', name: 'jakarta.xml.bind-api', version: '3.0.0'"

Comment: I think that you have the wrong jar in your classpath. It may be because of the classloading order. Try parent last to load your jars into the classpath first and then those of the server's jars.

Comment: Hi @user1578872. I am very happy to hear that the provided link was helpful. Regarding your current issue, it looks like Spring is unable to find a JAXB implementation in your classpath, although you provided the sun related ones. For the version of the `jaxb-api` that you indicated, please, remove the dependencies related with `com.sun.xml.bind` and include the following one: `implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.1'`. Please, can you try? I hope it helps.

Comment: @jccampanero Making some progress. I see the latest version is 3.0.0. Is this okay to use 2.3.1. Getting the same error with 3.0.0. But different error with 2.3.1. Added the error here.

Comment: @user1578872 I am happy to hear that you are making progress. Please, see the answer I provided, I think your current issue is related with the JAXB access type definition. Please, include the `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` annotation in your classes. can you try?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although you tested similar approaches, please, consider review [this Github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20256), especially the [last comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20256#issuecomment-558595570), I think it can be helpful.

Be sure to have an appropriate version of the JAXB runtime as well. In your previous issues it looks like Spring was unable to find a suitable JAXB implementation in your classpath. For the version of the `jaxb-api` that you indicated in your dependencies, `2.3.1`, please, remove the dependencies related with `com.sun.xml.bind` and include the following one:

```
implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '2.3.1'
```

The recent `org.glassfish.jaxb` `jaxb-runtime` versions, say `3.0.0`, depends on `org.glassfish.jaxb` `jaxb-core` which in turn depends on `jakarta.xml.bind` `jakarta.xml.bind-api`, the Eclipse Foundation based JAXB implementation for Java EE. If you want to use `org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:3.0.0` include the following dependency:

```
implementation group: 'jakarta.xml.bind', name: 'jakarta.xml.bind-api', version: '3.0.0'
```

instead of the previous JAXB API one you defined:

```
implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'
```

Please, change your imports in consequence and test it carefully, I never tested it with Spring `WebClient` and the related JAXB codecs.

Regarding the problem with the `section` repetition, it seems that JAXB is trying to serialize both field and methods defined properties of your POJOs. To avoid the problem, explicitly define the access type using the `@XmlAccessorType` annotation. For example:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="DirectoryOfService")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DirectoryOfService {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "Section")
    private Section section;

    
    public Section getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setSection(Section section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

}
```

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="Section")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Section {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "Test")
    private List<Test> test;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    //public String text;

    public List<Test> getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    
    public void setTest(List<Test> test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "Test")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Test {

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "Code")
    private String code;
    @XmlElement(name = "Replicate")
    private int replicate;
    @XmlElement(name = "ValidFrom")
    private Date validFrom;
    @XmlElement(name = "Includes")
    private String includes;
    @XmlElement(name = "Currency")
    private String currency;
    @XmlElement(name = "NonDiscountable")
    private boolean nonDiscountable;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    
    public int getReplicate() {
        return replicate;
    }

    
    public void setReplicate(int replicate) {
        this.replicate = replicate;
    }

    
    public Date getValidFrom() {
        return validFrom;
    }

    
    public void setValidFrom(Date validFrom) {
        this.validFrom = validFrom;
    }

    
    public String getIncludes() {
        return includes;
    }

    
    public void setIncludes(String includes) {
        this.includes = includes;
    }

    
    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    
    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    
    public boolean isNonDiscountable() {
        return nonDiscountable;
    }

    
    public void setNonDiscountable(boolean nonDiscountable) {
        this.nonDiscountable = nonDiscountable;
    }

}
```

Comment: implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.1'. Why it is not working with the latest version 3.0.0?

Comment: Hi @user1578872. Probably because of the `jaxb-api` version. The recent `org.glassfish.jaxb` `jaxb-runtime` versions, say, '3.0.0` depends on `jaxb-core` which in turn depends on `jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api`, the eclipse based JAXB implementation for Java EE. If you want to use `org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:3.0.0` use `implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.0'` instead of the former `javax` `jaxb-api` one. Please, can you try?  By the way, did it work the change related with the inclusion of the `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`annotation?

Comment: Same error with 3.0.0 even after including jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.0

Comment: Hi @user1578872. I am sorry to hear that. So, everything is working fine will 2.3.1 version but with 3.0.0 you are still facing the `JAXBContext` related problem?

Comment: Correct. Going with 2.3.1 for now.

Comment: I see. I will try to dig into it. In any way, I am happy to see that with the 2.3.1 version everything is running fine.